# Related object reference does not work without importing the related model itself

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I have 2 models in my app -

In models/parent.py I have -

```
 from django.db import models
 class Parent(models.Model): 
       class Meta:
          db_table = "parent_table"
       start_date = models.DateField()
       end_date = models.DateField()
```

In models/child.py I have -

```
from django.db import models
from models.parent import Parent
class Child(models.Model): 
   class Meta:
      db_table = "child_table"
   some_ref = models.ForeignField(Parent)
```

Now in models/parent.py I am defining a property as -

```
@property
def referred_values(self):
 return self.child_set.all()
```

It gives me error -

```
AttributeError: 'Parent' object has no attribute 'child_set'
```

But if I import Child class in any file in my app, it works fine.
Is this an expected behaviour or am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it your real models classes? why they are not inherit from `models.model`?

Comment: sorry I had missed it while typing, I have updated it in the question.

Comment: Your problem here is that `child_set` actually does not belong to a model - this is a model Manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is good to set related_name directly

```
some_ref = models.ForeignField(Parent, related_name='childs')
```

and use childs insted of child_set (more English)

Also you can use:

```
 some_ref = models.ForeignField(to='parent_app.Parent', related_name='childs')
```

and you do not need import Parent to Child models

Also:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
```

insted of

```
 class Parent:
```

But in your probrem, I think you forget add Child to models/__init__.py

Comment: Using related_name worked !! Thanks. It would be nice if you can give some insight on why it didn't work without using related_name.

Comment: I think, you forget add your model to models/__init__.py and django do not know about it untill you import it